# Holomorphic homeomorphisms

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

Let $M$ be a connected closed smooth manifold. Consider the group $\mathrm{Homeo}(M)$ of homeomorphisms $M\to M$ endowed with the $C^0$-topology.

If $M$ has a symplectic structure some people study the group of symplectic homeomorphisms. It is defined as the closure of the subgroup of symplectic diffeomorphisms in $\mathrm{Homeo}(M)$.

If $M$ has an almost complex structure what do we know about the closure of the subgroup of $J$-holomorphic diffeomorphisms in $\mathrm{Homeo}(M)$?

Comment: A question about this notion: could it happen that a homeomorphism $f$ is locally limit of symplectic homeomorphisms but not globally. By locally I mean that there is an covering $(U_i)$ of $M$, such that for every $i$, the homeomorphism $f:U_i\to f(V_i)$ is limit, uniformly on compact subsets, of symplectic diffeomorphisms $U_i\to V_i$ (or even of maps $U_i\to M$ that are symplectic diffeomorphisms onto their image). I'm just puzzled because for such a notion (and analogously for the almost complex analogue) one would expect to define homeomorphisms satisfying some local condition.

Comment: @YCor I think it is possible. See Section 1.5 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.0875